# How to make Django forms return only one error message instead of a list of error messages for one field?

Tags: django, forms, rest

I'm working with Django forms and Django REST Framework to create a project.

Now I'm wondering: how can I make Django return only ONE error message per form field instead of a list of error messages per form field?

I'll explain myself somehow further with a code example.

I defined a form in Django:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=200)
    url = forms.URLField(required=False, max_length=100)
    location = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=100)
```

And now I run the validation on this form in Django context (python manage.py shell):

```
>>> f=EditProfileForm({})
>>> f.is_valid()
False
>>> f._errors
{'name': [u'This field is required.']}
```

As you can see, the form errors returns a dictionary and there's a list of error messages present for the form field / key "name". How can I make sure that Django only returns ONE string as error messages instead of a list of error messages for this form field?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kind regards,
K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!

And the solution is: override the ErrorList class.

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.utils import ErrorList

class CustomErrorList(ErrorList):
     def as_text(self):
        return u'%s' % self[0]

class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.error_class = CustomErrorList
```

Now when you call the as_text() method, one and only one error message in the list (for the same key) is returned. Django is great, by the way! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As I'm looking in the Django code, I think I need to modify/override the ErorrList or ErrorDict classes with something else, but I'm not sure if this is a smart idea... I'm using Django 1.7.1 by the way.